# Secure site redirect to non secure default.aspx

Tags: ssl, iis, https, response.redirect

I have setup website in IIS as secure website. When Access login page using https://domainname/login.aspx it is secure. on successful login I am using response.rediret method to redirect to default.aspx. However this page is load as non secure (http://) how to resolve it ?

[image: Login Page]

defalut.aspx page is load as not secure
[image]

The website setup is secure - after successful log the default page must be secure.

Comment: The images are unnecessary. Just explain them with a few words. Also add an IIS tag.

Comment: Please post how did you redirect to default.aspx, you can click Not secure to get more information.

Comment: on successful login I am using c# code Response.Redirect("/default.aspx").

Comment: Is /default.aspx the complete path? Verify that the folder structure on your workstation looks the same as the folder structure deployed to the server.

Comment: folder structure is same, It is redirecting to the page as expected - but the issue is - it is not secure i.e "http"

Comment: Try to use failed request tracking to get detailed request information, which may help you find the problem.